# Не получается сделать фон для текста html

Tags: html

Как всё должно выглядеть:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я не могу понять, в чём я ошибся, но у меня не получается подобный фон для текста.

```css
.quote{
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 47px;
 font-family: "Segoe UI Light";
        font-weight: 300;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding-top: 18px;
 padding-left: 24px;
 padding-bottom: 17px;
 padding-right: 16px;
 background-color: rgba(76,80,90,0.85);
}

.q1{
 margin-top: 268px;
}

.q2{
 margin-top: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="quote q1">
 “I’m looking for the unexpected.
</div>
<div class="quote q2">
 I’m looking for things I’ve never seen before.”
</div>
```

Comment: Не получается добавить фон колосьев сзади?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

блоки занимают всю доступную ширину, нужен display:inline-block и перенос строки

```css
.list-h {
  margin-top: 268px;
  text-align: center;
}
.quote {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 47px;
  font-family: "Segoe UI Light";
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-top: 18px;
  padding-left: 24px;
  padding-bottom: 17px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  background-color: rgba(76, 80, 90, 0.85);
}

.q2 {
  margin-top: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-h">
  <span class="quote q1">
    “I’m looking for the unexpected.
  </span>
  <span class="quote q2">
    I’m looking for things I’ve never seen before.”
  </span>
</div>
```